# How can I call different methods when I press and release a button?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

How can I call a method when I press a button and call another when I release the button?

I'm working with a PTT (press to talk) button in my C# WinForms app.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`MouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown.aspx) and [`MouseUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup.aspx)   events

Comment: @MarkKram:- Oh sequence intermingled !! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   // button is being pressed
}

private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   // button was released
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this perhaps:

```
    private void btn1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mouse Button was pressed down on the button");
    }

    private void btn1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Mouse button Button was released");
    }
```

Take a look at the output windows after clicking the button.

### Updated

Ok try this, add a text box to your form and name it TextBox1 and then add this code to the code behind:

```
    private void btn1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TextBox1.Text = "Mouse Button was pressed down on the button";
    }

    private void btn1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TextBox1.Text = "Mouse button Button was released";
    }
```

Comment: My button is called buttonRCP and try the following:
`
private void buttonRCP_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mouse button Button was pressed down on the button");
        }

        private void buttonRCP_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mouse button Button was release");
        }
`

Comment: Did you check the output window ?